# Initializing a List of Interfaces

Tags: c#

I am trying to init this list.  However when I Add() that item I get the error:

> "Argument 1 cannot convert from void to IRule".

Wouldn't that testing method that consumes `IRule` be a valid member of this list?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    List<IRule> Rules { get; set; }

    public SomeClass()  // constructor
    {
        Rules = new List<IRule>()
        {
            Rules.Add(new testing());
        };
    }
}

public class testing : IRule
{
    // stuff from the interface
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rules = new List<IRule>()
 {
    Rules.Add(new testing());
 };
```

In side the { } you are giving a list of values to add to the list.  You can't reference the list the error is telling you that in an odd way.

You can either

```
Rules = new List<IRule>() { new testing()};
```

or

```
Rules = new List<IRule>();
Rules.Add(new testing());
```

But you can't mix the styles.